# React - I want to run a function when the component unmounts, how do I use the latest state variables?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have a component that takes a prop 'self'. I have a state 'value' that defaults to 'self'. Both these values are boolean. I have a button on my screen that toggles value between true and false. When the component unmounts (whenever the user goes back or to a different page), I want to run a function if in case value is different from self. Basically, If there is a change from the initial value, I want to update my DB.

I tried a useEffect and it's return statement but that doesn't use the latest state.
I tried using a dependency variable to run the useEffect but that run on every change of the state or click of the button, which is not ideal.
I tried a useRef which also doesn't seem to work. This is the code for the useRef

```
const { routine, self } = route.params
  const [value, setValue] = useState(self);
  const progressRef = createRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Ran first', progressRef.current)
    return function a() {
      if(progressRef.current==null) return;
      // if(self==progressRef.current) return;
      console.log('Return', self, value, progressRef.current)
    }
  }, []);  


  const onChange = () => {
    progressRef.current = value;
    console.log('Changed', progressRef.current);
    setValue((value)=>!value);
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
         <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>onChange()}>
          <View style={{marginLeft: 150, width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor:value?'red':'blue'}}></View>
         </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
```

The ref, however, is not changing to show the last change within the useEffect's return function. Here's the output on console

[image]

Ideally, I want it to run only when value is different from self when the component unmounts.

Comment: you should be using the `useRef` hook rather than `createRef`. I think that will solve your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read about [`createRef`](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/createRef#declaring-a-ref-in-a-class-component)

> **Caveats**
>
> - `createRef` always returns a *different* object. It’s equivalent to writing `{ current: null }` yourself.
> - In a function component, you probably want [`useRef`](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useRef) instead which always returns the same object.
> - `const ref = useRef()` is equivalent to `const [ref, _] = useState(() => createRef(null))`.

So you get the classic scope issue (*a closure around a specific variable*). Your click handler the first time references the initial object created by `createRef` and so will set it to `true` but the subsequent re-renders will create different refs.

The `useEffect` only has access to the object create in the first render, and will remain with that value until un-mount.

Use `useRef` instead.

Comment: Yep! I can't believe how long I took trying to solve that. Thanks a ton!